# PSU Connectors won't fit

Tags: power-supply, sata, cable

I just bought a new PSU to replace one that blew up a few weeks ago.

Everything went fine except that none of the 4 detachable SATA and Peripheral cables that came with the supply will connect to it. I can't really explain concisely in words, so here are some pictures that show the problem:

This is the cable:

[image: The offending cable]

...and these are the sockets on the PSU it should connect to:

[image: The PSU sockets]

Look closely at the PSU and you'll see that those two will clearly never fit together.

So my question is... why? I've never fitted a power supply before, so am I missing something or have I just been sent the wrong cables?

Comment: See if your board has a plug in it for one of the SATA power cables, then plug your other cable into your disk. My Intel DH61AG board had like 3 different types of power connectors, and 3 SATA plugs or something... it took me a while to realize there was a place on my mobo for 'SATA Power' - what is your motherboard?

Comment: @ekaj Gigabyte GA-P55M-UD2. I've had a look (Both on the board itself and in the manual) and there's no mention of anything like that...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is a mistake by manufacturer. The wrong connectors were spilled into mix and assembling robot never noticed the mistake.

But If you know your pinouts and can test the actual voltages and see if expected values are correct, you can use exacto knife and carefully correct one wrongly shaped pin. Or use a scalpel blade.

Comment: ...it's probably safest that I don't try that. I'll just return it and get a new one. Thanks though.